# After selecting option from menu, Activity freezes

Tags: android, menu

I am a little new in developing for android devices, so if my question is trivial, I am sorry, but I have not been able to solve this for about 6 hours. 
I have a problem with the common menu. I am able to show the menu correctly and also make everything work in reaction. The problem is that the Activity on which I am calling it freezes after execution. 
I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game: 
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I have tried deleting all logic from the case block that you see here, but the effect is the same as before. After I press the menu Item which belongs to "R.id.new_game", the Activity freezes. 
It is not the full application that freezes, becouse I am able to open the menu again and select the option that I want. However all items (like buttons ..) are disabled.

I have also tried redirecting to another activity - it works well but if I use the back button on a mobile device, the activity is frozen.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your problem is in the code you've provided.  Does anything else get called or stopped when you click on the menu?

Answer (score 0):

try and:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   <- remove this line
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game: 
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

wild guess though, so sorry if it doesn't fix the problem. your code works in a newly created app, but I've never seen calling super before returning it in the default branch.

Comment: You are right. I did not have it also. However in some searching I found opinion that it is not bad to give it there. 
After commenting it, it still freezes. 
Anyway, thanks for reply.

Comment: how did you fix this issue?